# How to build docker to run Python3 from Node.js child_process in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, node.js, docker, google-app-engine, runtime

I'm deploying node.js web application on custom runtime with flex environment. I'm calling child_process in Node.js to open python3 as such:

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
pythonProcess = spawn('python3');
```

Which runs fine **locally** but when deployed to GAE, it gives me an error as such:

```
Error: spawn python3 ENOENT
   at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:240)
   at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415)
   at process._tickCallback (next_tick.js:63)
```

**However, when I run python2, it works fine.**

After doing some research and digging, I came across this question on stackoverflow

[How to install Python3 in Google Cloud Platform for a Node app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55829115/how-to-install-python3-in-google-cloud-platform-for-a-node-app)

It seems that I have to do something with **building custom runtime from docker file** to allow multiple runtimes (something like that).

I've tried countless things with docker file such as:

```
# Trying to install python3
FROM ubuntu as stage0
WORKDIR /python/
RUN apt-get update || : && apt-get install --yes python3;
RUN apt-get install python3-pip -y

# My main node.js docker stuff 
FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/nodejs
COPY . /app/
... etc
```

and

```
# From google app engine python runtime docker repo
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/python
RUN virtualenv /env
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env
ENV PATH /env/bin:$PATH
ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt
ADD . /app

# My main node.js docker stuff 
FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/nodejs
COPY . /app/
... etc
```

which none of it worked.

What is the correct approach of doing this and how can I do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google's image](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docker/blob/master/runtime-image/Dockerfile) is based on ubuntu but only has python 2 and 2.7. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59528343/1267201) showed how to use python3.6, but we're going to install 3.5 it via software-properties-common. Putting things together, you get:

```
FROM launcher.gcr.io/google/nodejs
# same as
# FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/nodejs


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install software-properties-common -y
# RUN unlink /usr/bin/python
# RUN ln -sv /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/python
# RUN python -V
RUN python3 -V

# Copy application code.
COPY . /app/

# Install dependencies.
RUN npm --unsafe-perm install
```

If you're just going to call `python3` from your spawn, you don't need to unlink (commented lines) which I included so that you can just call python.

Comment: Wow, that did it, thanks!! Also one more question if you dont mind. Would you also know how to install python3 libraries and use them as well? Thanks!!

Comment: hey... for python you need pip as package manager, same as NPM for node. maybe google around it. i was never quite sure how to deal with multiple pythons and pips for them sorry :( i'll have a look when there's a spare min